# C file in QT creator, and library issues

Tags: qt, libraries

i work on windows environment, i have installed QT creator recently and wanted to execute a c program from .c file in QT. There are couple of problems why the file does not compile, first it does not recognize the library headers "time.h" "math.h" and even "stdio.h"

Two, i'm not sure if it will compile even after fixing the library, because i changed the include path in the .pro file to the path of the libraries. and still had a proble of compilation.

Is there a way, that the compiler knows that the file is .c instead of c++...how can i proceed.

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the text of the compiler error?

Comment: How does your .pro file look like, assuming you use qmake?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you installed the IDE but not the SDK.  The SDK comes with gcc and the standard libraries that you are referring to.  If you need to use your own separate compiler, you can configure it in Qt Creator > Tools > Options > Build and Run > Tool Chains.

Some additional information may be found here for your issue:

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/33974-Compiling-c-files-using-C-and-QT

So, my suggestion is to download the full SDK of Qt, and then pick and choose the elements you want, and make sure it includes a compiler.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Easy to check if it is an issue witht the IDE. just use `qmake /Pathtopro; make` in the command line. And the information on your link is not 100% reliable: "most C code is also C++" is just wrong.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I just wanted to put something about using C with Qt and that was one of the first things google spit out.